# android date localization

Tags: android

I'm storing a date as string somewhere in my app. like this:

```
Date updatedDate = new Date();

SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(Constants.Preferences.LastUpdateDateKey, updatedDate.toLocaleString());
editor.commit();
```

Everything works fine when the language is English.

But when I switch it to french.

this code throw an illegalArgumentException

```
String lastUpdateDateString = settings.getString(Constants.Preferences.LastUpdateDateKey, null);

if(lastUpdateDateString!=null){             
            lastUpdateDate = new Date(Date.parse(lastUpdateDateString));             
        }
```

it throws at Date.parse

Both english and french, the updatedDate.toLocaleString() is in this format: 2011-12-16 22:13:32

It must have something to do with the language switch. Is there a way to say parse the date using a format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` this will give you the date and it will be fixed for every locale

Syntax is `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

the if you want to get string then you can use

```
dateFormat.format(new Date())
```

and if you want to get Date from String then

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse(strDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by using SimpleFormatter.